# Is it possible to get player country information from google play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I want to create custom leaderboard for my game using information from google play service leaderboard. Is it possible to get country information for each player in leaderboard?

Couldn't find if there is information about player country in google play service, but I played some games containing leaderboard with visible country for each player in it. I'm not sure if these games used google play service for leaderboard.

Comment: You can probably use Google Maps Geocoder API to get the user's location and eventually the country's name. See [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-google-map-search-location-using-geocodr).